# Strange error on one web server in our production environment: MissingMethod exception, though I don't think a method is missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, structuremap

We're running a web application distributed across load balanced 3 web servers. The exact same code base & configuration is deployed across the 3 servers, and since about 1 hour ago I'm getting the following error on one of them, but not the other two.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XXX.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

We are running this with ASP.NET MVC (with Output Caching), NHibernate (with NHibernate caching) & StructureMap. The cache is not shared, so each web server manages its own cache, though the cache dependencies are the same across the 3 servers.

I don't really know where to start describing what/where it could be going wrong or the circumstances, because it's so strange to me.

I've seen this once before about 2 weeks ago, but it went away on its own after about an hour and I haven't seen it since. Has anyone else seen an error like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems your HomeController is missing a parameterless constructor. Are you sure it has one? 
The default controller factory needs one to intialize your constructor.

Unless you are using your own ControllerFactory, in which case you need to register it during Application_Start:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     //other code

     ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyCustomControllerFactory());
}
```

Comment: yes, I'm certain it has one especially considering that the same code base works fine on 2 other web servers, and that it only stopped working since this morning. It's been working fine for weeks before this.

Comment: You know, I just checked and in fact there *isn't* a parameterless constructor for HomeController. None of my Controllers have Parameterless constructors, but none have ever needed them. I'm very hesitant to just add parameterless constructors though, because that kind of smells of shotgun debugging.

Comment: @DaveDev: Hmm... Perhaps your Application_Start never fired. Did it perhaps go away after a server restart/ web.config change/ App pool recycle?

Comment: I don't know what fixed it the first time. I'm hesitant to restart the application at this point because I don't want to overwrite any 'clues' to what it might be, but I do expect that will resolve it. I can see in the Event Viewer's Application log that there are a lot of errors coming from w3wp.exe. Our sysadmin guy is telling me to just do an IIS reset, so I guess this is one of those things that'll get swept under the rug until next time.

Comment: @DaveDev: BTW, You don't need a Parameterless constructor if you register your own ControllerFactory. However, when that line of code never gets called (if Application_Start was never raised), it will try to find that Parameterless Contructor and report an error if it can't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're resolving controllers with structuremap, it may be your components are registered at the wrong place/time.

Are you registering components in Application_Start ?

Comment: Yes, everything is registered in application_start.